# How to initialize the client context from another user's account

Tags: sharepoint-2013, impersonation, csom

Currently I am working on .net web api's that are called from non-SharePoint pages to run SharePoint code to perform certain actions. I have shared configured visual studio so that every one can access the page through my system's IP URL. The code in web api is working fine expect for the fact that it is always taking my account to perform every action.

So how can we run the client context from another users account if I have the domain name of the user.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web web = clientContext.Web;
User user = web.EnsureUser(@"domain\user1");
clientContext.Load(user);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
string title = user.Title;
string loginName = user.LoginName;
```

If I want to run the clientcontext under this user name. How can i do that. I found the code below that works in server side

```
SPUserToken userToken = web.AllUsers[user].UserToken;
SPSite s = new SPSite(siteStr, userToken);
SPWeb w = s.OpenWeb();
Console.WriteLine("Currently logged in as: " +
                  w.CurrentUser.ToString() +
                  "(" + w.CurrentUser.Name + ")"
                 );
```

What is the alternative for this code in CSOM.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can use NetworkCredential method to pass the user credential, the code snippet below for your reference:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Some List");
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    //do something
}
```

**Reference**: [Authentication when using the SharePoint client object model](https://sharepointdragons.com/2012/04/20/authentication-when-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not possible to pass the password, as the system is going to be AD authenticated and I dont think we can fetch the password from the AD in any case.

Comment: You can custom a login page for user login. Or as a workaround, you can create a custom web service and use Server Side Object Model to impersonate users, then consume the web service in client side.